# Make Capistrano use alias on sever when running scripts

Tags: php, capistrano, capistrano3

I have the following problem using Capistrano with laravel:

- My hosting provider does not provide a cli php version via `php` but only via a `usr/bin/local/.../PHP-CLI` command
- I did create an alias for it in my `.bash_profile` so running `composer install` from the cli is no problem.

However, Capistrano (as far as I understand due to it starting in a very basic shell http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) does not load this alias, so I get an error from the composer scripts e.g. `php artisan`.

However, on my dev machine I need to keep it as php, since this is where php is here.

How can I solve this problem best? Any more info you need? Thanks.

Just in case it helps, this is how I call the script:

```
desc 'Composer install'
task :composer_install do
    on roles(:app), in: :groups, limit:1 do
        execute "/usr/local/bin/php5-56STABLE-CLI composer.phar install --working-dir #{fetch(:release_path)}"
        execute "cp #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/shared/.env #{fetch(:release_path)}/.env"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my current workaround is the following:

in your capistrano `deploy.rb` in the script that you execute at deploy update.

```
    desc 'Composer install'
    task :composer_install do
        on roles(:app), in: :groups, limit:1 do
            execute "/usr/local/bin/php5-56STABLE-CLI /path/to/composer.phar install --working-dir #{fetch(:release_path)} --no-scripts"
            execute "cd #{fetch(:release_path)} && /usr/local/bin/php5-56STABLE-CLI artisan clear-compiled"
            execute "cd #{fetch(:release_path)} && /usr/local/bin/php5-56STABLE-CLI artisan optimize"
        end
    end

end

after "deploy:updated", "deploy:composer_install"
```

I am not 100% sure if the `artisan clear-compiled` is needed. Anyway, those 2 are composer scripts that would normally be called via composer, but the `--no-scripts` flag keeps them from being called, so that it does not fail on install. When calling them from capistrano, I can easily change which `php` to use, as you can see.

However if anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your scenario is the perfect fit for Capistrano's "command map" feature, as documented here: https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map.

Here are the two main takeaways:

1. Write your Capistrano `execute` commands so that the binary name (`php`) is a separate argument. This will allow it to be substituted using the command map. For example:

   ```
   execute :php, "composer.phar install --working-dir #{fetch(:release_path)}"
   ```
2. In your Capistrano deployment config, tell the command map how to substitute the `:php` command, like this:

   ```
   SSHKit.config.command_map[:php] = "/usr/local/bin/php5-56STABLE-CLI"
   ```

If you want this substitution to affect all deployment environments, place it in `deploy.rb`. If it only applies to your production environment, then put it in `production.rb`.

Comment: Hey, I think this will not work (correct me if I'm wrong) because the php call is within the composer.json file, and this file needs to run on my dev machine without Capistrano. So your solution would not work, correct? Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: I can not substitute php like I can using a bash alias, correct?

Comment: Right, this substitution only works for `php` calls done by explicit Capistrano `execute` commands. My answer won't help if the `php` commands are buried inside another script.